Cannot install Flutter APK files directly through WhatsApp, as it treats them as BIN format
When I send the release APK via WhatsApp, the installer doesn't detect it as an APK file; it shows as a BIN file and can't be installed. However, it works fine when accessed directly from the Downloads folder.
Unlike React Native APKs, which install directly through WhatsApp, Flutter APKs show as BIN files and cannot be installed when sent via WhatsApp.

When you share the APK file to WhatsApp and you see BIN, it's actually a WhatsApp bug and has nothing to do with Flutter. Netizens have also reported that PDF's that was shared on WhatsApp are shown as BIN (Binary file), hence they are unable to access it.
Solution

Locate the APK file on your Android file manager Android/media/com.whatsapp/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Documents/.

Share to file through other means, USB cord, Bluetooth, Google drive etc.

Use adb CLI to install the application directly on your phone; adb install path-to-apk


